# reactiveui whenany on dependency property

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have simple WPF app with two textboxes and ReactiveUI.  I try to lookup for dependency property of first textbox by using WhenAny

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        RxApp.DeferredScheduler = DispatcherScheduler.Current;
        InitializeComponent();
        Text1.WhenAny(i => i.Text, i => i.Value).Subscribe(_ => SomeMethod());

    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Boom!");
    }

}
```

My Form code is

```
<Window x:Class="TestObservable.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="Text1" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="Text2" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

</Grid>
```

BUT When I change TextBox Text it doesn't show to me

What's the problem?

Comment: ReactiveUI is a MVVM framework. Where is your ViewModel?

Comment: It's demonstration of error, I has viewmodel but it is too complicated to show this here

Comment: Using the above, I'm not able to get any error.  It works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.Text1.Text, x => x.Value);
```

If it doesn't work, I believe you're being bitten by a bug in ReactiveUI 4.1. Upgrading to 4.2 (released a few days ago) may fix it.