# two whenany on one object bug

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I use reactiveUI for watching properties of DP
The code is

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        RxApp.DeferredScheduler = DispatcherScheduler.Current;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WhenAny(i => i.Width, i => i.Value).Subscribe(_ => SomeMethod("Width"));
        this.WhenAny(i => i.Height, i => i.Value).Subscribe(_ => SomeMethod("Height"));
    }

    void SomeMethod(string hello)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(hello);
    }

}
```

When I resize window by height there is no messagebox
But when I resize window by width there is two messageboxes
When I comment any of these whenany's it works very well, but with two whenanys work improperly

I know I can watch two propeties by one whenany but I need to watch two dependency properties of differentType by two WhenAny

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried listening for ActualWidth and ActualHeight. My guess is Width and Height are not changing similar because of your window resizing behavior, ActualXYZ should work no matter what.

Comment: No. It works the same way. The problem is two whenany on one object. I'm waiting for Paul Betts' answer

Comment: I'm used to using RXUI in a view model that inherits from ReactiveObject, perhaps that's an approach you can use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910958/reactiveui-whenany-on-dependency-property

Comment: @kenny it's my question and it is question about another theme. And I can't use ReactiveObject in above question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. Can you file this bug over at http://github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui/issues? In the meantime, you might have to use a shim, something like:

```
var changedObservable = new Subject<Unit>();
this.SizeChanged += (o,e) => changedObservable.OnNext(Unit.Default);
```